# How to import database connection class in another class in php

Tags: php, oop

I am going to import DatabaseConnector class in Controller class. DatabaseConnector class contains database connection queries. Both classes are different php file.

Here is my code.

DatabaseConnector:

```
class DatabaseConnector
{
    public $con;
    //function for getting connected to database
    public function getConnection()
    {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","abcd");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        return $con;
    }
    public function closeConnection()
    {
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
include "database_connector.php";
    $dc = new DatabaseConnector();
    $con = $dc->getConnection();
class Controller
{

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function insertData()
    {

        $name = "Abcde";
        $sql = "insert into user_details values('".$name."')";
        mysql_query($con, $sql);
    }


}
```

Where i am wrong in this code. it shows me error on mysql_query($con,$sql): $con in undefined variable;
and mysql_query() requires two parameters

Please help me.

Comment: Change `mysql_query($con, $sql);` to `mysqli_query($con, $sql);` you cannot mix MySQL APIs. It's not like rhum & coke. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` when in development.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$con` is not in the class.

```
include "database_connector.php";
class Controller
{
    protected $con;

    public function __construct(){
        $dc = new DatabaseConnector();
        $this->con = $dc->getConnection();
    }

    public function insertData()
    {
        $name = "Abcde";
        $sql = "insert into user_details values('".$name."')";
        mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);
    }
}
```

I don't test the code, but this should work.